# Combining different fonts

Tags: fonts, packages, compilation-error

I am writing a note and I tried to combine two different fonts taken from *The latex fonts catalogue* [here](https://tug.org/FontCatalogue/mathfonts.html).

These fonts are *New TX* for the text style and *GFS Artemisia with Euler math* for math style. However, as I expected, they do not combine properly as the latex compiler gives me the following error

```
! LaTeX Error: Command \textfrac already defined.
               Or name \end... illegal, see p.192 of the manual.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.72 ...rnums}{m}{textdenomnums}\selectfont /#2}}}
                                                  
?
```

Is there any way for getting rid of that?

Here is the code.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{amsart}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{newtxtext, gfsartemisia-euler}


\begin{document}

$\mathbb{Z}$

\end{document}
```

This are all packages I am using.

Comment: Thanks @DavidCarlisle for the answer. I am using overleaf and I do not know how to show the other lines, I try. However it says "Command \textfrac already defined", I do not know whether this might help.

Comment: yes it is, I fix it!

Comment: On its own right it doesn't, right. I guess the problem is that I am combining it with newtxtext

Comment: thanks I cleaned up my comments now the example helps!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

when loading multiple font packages there is always the chance that they define the same top level commands. It may be that you don't use `\textfrac` at all and you don't care which version you use but you need to tell latex one or the other, here I load tx then undefine `\textfrac` then load gfs so its definition will win.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{amsart}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{newtxtext}

\let\textfrac\undefined
\usepackage{gfsartemisia-euler}



\begin{document}

$\mathbb{Z}$

\end{document}
```

Comment: It works! Thanks a lot.