# How to use Bodoni Italic (non-default font)

Tags: fonts

[This](http://mirrors.ctan.org/fonts/greek/gfs/gfsbodoni/tex/gfsbodoni.sty) is the **gfsbodoni.sty** file. I don't know how to *italicise* the text. The text is only for a section in the document.
Using Overleaf, pdflatex.

What I tried and they produce non-italicised text:

- `\textit{{\fontfamily{gfs}\selectfont Bodoni Italic. \lipsum[2-4]}}`
- `\fontfamily{gfs}\selectfont \itshape Bodoni Italic. \lipsum[2-4]}`

The font is non-default. So I use some fonts using specific commands (`\fibrabook` is an example), and some using these 3 letters. The fonts all work, because I read that I can find info in the .sty file. However, I am confused on how to italicise it now that I have it

**EDIT: Complete shortcode**

```
\documentclass[a5paper,pagesize,10pt,bibtotoc,pointlessnumbers,
normalheadings,DIV=9,twoside=false]{scrbook}

\KOMAoptions{DIV=last}
\usepackage{gfsbodoni}
\usepackage{tgadventor}
\usepackage[scaled]{berasans}
\usepackage[bitstream-charter]{mathdesign}
\usepackage{scholax}
\usepackage{palatino}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\begin{document}
\newpage
\poiretonefamily
PoiretOne. \lipsum[2-4]
\newpage
\textbf{\textit{Times. \lipsum[2-4]}}
\newpage
\textit{{\fontfamily{gfs}\selectfont Bodoni Italic. \lipsum[2-4]} }
\end{document}
```

I probably didn't include everything necessary, but I don't see how the problem is not clear, so please give me details of why the problem is not clear. I imagine \textit or \itshape would italicise a font, but they don't. The font shows normally.

Comment: Could you please post a complete short code reproducing your problem?

Comment: I edited the post to include the code

Comment: Which is your default font?

Comment: It's Palatino, that is why I have no idea how to control whether Bodoni shows in italics only using those 3 letters

Comment: I have several error messages, one of them saying that  gfsbodoni is not defined in T1 encoding, albeit I have a `T1bodoni.fd` file on my system,  which looks very strange.

Comment: Keep in mind I'm using pdflatex to compile

Comment: I also compiled with pdflatex. I even refreshed my filenames database. There seems to be problems with this package.

Comment: Maybe there's something specific for Overleaf that makes it work, I have no clue how it works.

Comment: What is strange is that it  asserts it does not exist in T1 encoding.   Usually, when we have a problem with a type 1 font, it comes the database of type1 fonts was not refreshed (through the corresponding  .map file).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [package documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/fonts/greek/gfs/gfsbodoni/doc/gfsbodoni.pdf) of `gfsbodoni` the package defines the command `\textbodoni{}` for short texts and the environment `\begin{bodoni}\end{bodoni}` for longer texts.

Both indeed work (note that I removed some deprecated options for `scrbook`):

```
\documentclass[DIV=9,twoside=false]{scrbook}

\KOMAoptions{DIV=last}
\usepackage{gfsbodoni}
\usepackage{tgadventor}
\usepackage[scaled]{berasans}
\usepackage[bitstream-charter]{mathdesign}
\usepackage{scholax}
\usepackage{palatino}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
Default font \lipsum[1]

\textbodoni{Bodoni Regular \lipsum[2]}

\begin{bodoni}
\textit{Bodoni Italic. \lipsum[3]}
\end{bodoni}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Font properties of the PDF:

[image]

Comment: Out of curiosity, which distribution do you have? I couldn't make it work with MiKTeX.

Comment: This worked. However, future readers, please be aware my problem was also related to package clashes. I had too many fonts that defined properties that gfs bodoni was using. Good luck and thank you @Marijn

Comment: What about the error stopping every LaTeX run?

Comment: @egreg I'm not really sure which error you refer to? When I run the code in my answer I don't get any errors or warnings (TeX Live 2019). Maybe a newer compiler has introduced errors?

Comment: @Marijn With TL 2021 the error is about `\textfrac` being already defined (the culprit is `gfsbodoni`).

Comment: @egreg I see, another issue caused by the lack of proper package scoping in LaTeX it seems. For future readers: if you encounter this error then something like https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/601978/combining-different-fonts/601983 might help you.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry, but loading

```
\usepackage{gfsbodoni}
\usepackage{tgadventor}
\usepackage[scaled]{berasans}
\usepackage[bitstream-charter]{mathdesign}
\usepackage{scholax}
\usepackage{palatino}
```

does not make sense. The packages do, for their main job,

```
% gfsbodoni
\renewcommand{\rmdefault}{bodoni}}% if loaded with the default option
% tgadventor
\renewcommand{\sfdefault}{qag}
% berasans
\renewcommand{\sfdefault}{fvs}
% mathdesign with bitstream-charter
\renewcommand{\rmdefault}{mdbch}
% scholax
\renewcommand*{\rmdefault}{TeXGyreScholaX-TLF}% at begin document
% palatino
\renewcommand{\rmdefault}{ppl}
\renewcommand{\sfdefault}{phv}
\renewcommand{\ttdefault}{pcr}
```

The net result is that the chosen fonts are

- TeX Gyre Schola as default font
- Helvetica for sans serif
- Courier for monospace

plus setting up math with Charter (very incompatible with Schola).

You should make a decision about what main fonts you want to use, taking into account that `palatino` is obsolete.

If you want Schola and also support for math, you can use `fouriernc`.

You might want to choose accompanying sans serif and monospaced fonts. But do yourself a favor: never load several font packages, as incompatibilities are behind the corner.

You also use `\poiretonefamily` that's not defined in any of the packages you load. This is defined in a further font package.

Now let's tackle the problem. For your own reasons you want some paragraphs in Bodoni italic. There are two choices, one is `gfsbodoni`, the other is `librebodoni`.

```
\documentclass[
  a5paper,
  pagesize,
  10pt,
  bibliography=totoc,
  numbers=noenddot,
  headings=normal,
  DIV=9,
  twoside=false
]{scrbook}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{fouriernc} % math compatible with New Century Schoolbook
\usepackage{scholax}   % clone of New Century Schoolbook

\usepackage{lipsum}

\KOMAoptions{DIV=last}

\makeatletter
\def\LibreBodoni@scale{0.95}
\makeatother

\newenvironment{gfsbodoniitalic}
 {\fontfamily{bodoni}\itshape}%
 {}
\newenvironment{librebodoniitalic}
 {\fontfamily{LibreBodoni-TLF}\itshape}
 {}

\begin{document}

This is Schola with $a+b=\sin x$ some math.

\lipsum[2][1-4]

\begin{gfsbodoniitalic}
This is Bodoni Italic (GFS Bodoni)

\lipsum[3][1-4]
\end{gfsbodoniitalic}

\begin{librebodoniitalic}
This is Bodoni Italic (Libre Bodoni)

\lipsum[3][1-4]
\end{librebodoniitalic}

Is the scale RIGHT\begin{gfsbodoniitalic}RIGHT\end{gfsbodoniitalic} or not?

Is the scale RIGHT\begin{librebodoniitalic}RIGHT\end{librebodoniitalic} or not?

\end{document}
```

[image]

After comparing the possibilities, I'd go with LibreBodoni (that is, assuming you really want an extraneous font in your document).

Note also the options to the document class, with the newer ones instead of the deprecated ones.

Comment: According to the documentation, as I understand it, it seems  gsfbodoni defines bodoni as the default if you add the `[default]` option at load time.

Comment: @Bernard Yes. But it also does several dubious things and I'd not use it.

Comment: I agree with you. In another comment, I pointed that I could not make the code work with MiKTeX.

Comment: @Bernard I reworked the answer after a deeper plunge in those packages.

Comment: You could make it work! I confess I'm not a TeXpert, I only know well a number of packages, and understand roughly how they work.